# get facebook photo like count,share count,comment count

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I writting a service that collect this counter of facebook posts. Users enter posts link, and then i get from the link the postID, and by using this FQL:

```
"SELECT like_info.like_count, comment_info.comment_count, share_count FROM stream WHERE post_id='xxx_xxxx' AND created_time > 01/04/2014 AND created_time < 02/04/2014 limit 1000",
```

I get this counters.

The problem I have is when user enter a link to facebook photo (for example: http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10152281007419070&set=a.39727214069.46046.633269069&type=1&stream_ref=10),

then  how do I get the `postID`? I know that the `useriD` is the number after the second dot in the link, but how do i get the other number?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: The language i'm using is C#.

Answer (score 0):

The post id in the url you have mentioned is the `101522.......` ie just after `fbid=`

So, you can parse the url string and fetch the `photoid`

Comment: i don't know where to use this number. Putting it in the FQL query i wrote in my orginal post wan't bring results. Querying the photo or the album tables also dosn't help.